# TSQL to get a list of all users and when they last logged on in crowddb

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

We have a crowddatabase and are trying to get a list of every user and when they last logged on. On Atlassians website there is a query but only for MySQL, the query is:

```
SELECT 
  cwd_user.user_name, 
  from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000) 
FROM cwd_user, cwd_user_attribute 
WHERE cwd_user_attribute.user_id = cwd_user.id 
  AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticated'
```

I need to rewrite it for mssql and tried with

```
SELECT 
  cwd_user.user_name, 
  dateadd(s,12345,1/1/1970) 
  select cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value 
FROM cwd_user, cwd_user_attribute 
WHERE cwd_user_attribute.user_id = cwd_user.id 
  AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticated'
```

but get error The multi-part identifier "cwd_user.user_name" could not be bound.

Anyone who can help with the query?

Comment: Could you tag appropriate database tagging , for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `SELECT` in your SQL.

Remove the `SELECT` and change the `DATEADD` function slightly.

```
SELECT 
  cwd_user.user_name, 
  DATEADD(SECOND,(CAST(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value AS BIGINT)/1000),'1970-01-01')
FROM cwd_user, cwd_user_attribute 
WHERE cwd_user_attribute.user_id = cwd_user.id 
  AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticated';
```

Additionally, you should probably rewrite to support the 'new' `JOIN` syntax (by 'new', I mean ANSI-92)

```
SELECT 
  cwd_user.user_name, 
  DATEADD(SECOND,(CAST(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value AS BIGINT)/1000),'1970-01-01')
FROM cwd_user
INNER JOIN cwd_user_attribute 
   ON cwd_user_attribute.user_id = cwd_user.id 
  AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticated';
```

Comment: If I try the first one I get "Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the varchar value '1503317720480' overflowed an int column." and if I try the second one I get Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The conversion of the varchar value '1503317720480' overflowed an int column.
any thoughts to why?

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, it's a `VARCHAR`? Your initial query suggested it was an `INT`. Check updated answer

Comment: This worked perfectly. Sorry I missed it but in the learning process with tsql. Thank you for your help!